# Compare small values with zero with specific accuracy

Tags: c, decimal, floating-accuracy

I have a program which prints out a matrix with very small values. An example of my matrix is

```
0.00000000000000004  0.12300000000000000

0.00000000011111114  0.00000000000038544
```

What I would like to do is compare each value with `zero` and accept it to be `zero` with specific accuracy, which is 9 decimal places. In other words, if a number has 9 `zeros` as its first decimal values, I want to consider it as a `zero`, otherwise not.

I have searched a lot but really found nothing about it. Any ideas?

Comment: Compare `-1e-9 <= f <= 1e-9`?

Comment: @MicroVirus yes that worked, thanks so much!! I used the right part of your condition, `f <= 1e-9`. Could you explain what the left part, ` -1e-9 <= f`, checks?

Comment: @Marievi: `-1e-9` has 9 zeros as its first decimal values!!!

Comment: @barakmanos I am sorry if asking stupid questions, but then what is the difference between the left and the right part of the condition? I mean, why do I need them both?

Comment: @Marievi: What will you get for `f == -1` if you don't use the left part of the condition?

Comment: @barakmanos So the left part is for negative numbers... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, you can simply compare the float `f` via `-1e-9 < f < 1e-9`.

The you need both the positive and negative boundary to ensure it works properly for positive and negative numbers. You use `1e-9` and not `1e-10` because if a number is smaller than `1e-9`, a number with 8 decimals 0, then it has 9 decimals or more zero.

Do note that due to float rounding of `1e-9` when going from decimal to binary, you might see some rounding error.

Comment: Thanks so much @MicroVirus!!

Answer (score 2):

My idea is similar to what @MicroVirus has mentioned in his comment. You can simply compare it to a specific number:

```
if(num < 1E-9 && num > -1E-9)
    num = 0;
```

or

```
if(num * 1E9 < 1 && num * 1E9 > -1)
    num = 0;
```

Comment: Seems appropriate to give at least some credit to @MicroVirus's comment.

Comment: @barakmanos We happened to have the same idea. Edited anyway.